# Firebase Admob - Banner Ad overlapping the navigation drawer

Tags: navigation-drawer, flutter

After adding firebase_admob plugin and getting it up and running I noticed it overlays the fab and navigation drawer. I've fixed the fab using persistentFooterButtons but I can't seem to find a workaround for the navigation-drawer. Any help is much appreciated.

Find below a sample implementation, to recreate the issue in flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Firebase AdMob',
            theme: new ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: new MyHomePage(title: 'AdMob Test App'),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    int _counter = 0;
    BannerAd myBanner;

    void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
            _counter++;
        });
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        myBanner = new BannerAd(
            // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
            // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
            // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
            adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
            size: AdSize.smartBanner,
            targetingInfo: new MobileAdTargetingInfo(
                // gender: MobileAdGender.unknown
            ),
            listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
                print("BannerAd event is $event");
            },
        );
        myBanner..load()..show(
            // Banner Position
            anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
        );
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        myBanner?.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text(widget.title),
            ),
            drawer: new Drawer(),
            body: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        new Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
                        new Text('$_counter', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                tooltip: 'Increment',
                child: new Icon(Icons.add),
            ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to this but had same problem.

My nav drawer lives in a scrollable container with a fixed height so that it stops above the add and is scrollable. May not be perfect answer but works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Also using `PlatformVIew` is another way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was the same Added by @moehagene. I added an empty item to the bottom of the drawer with the height of the Ad, so the drawer becomes scrollable when there is not enough space and the Ad is showing. I think this is reasonable. Code below:

```
 return Drawer(
  // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
  // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
  // space to fit everything.
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: ListView(
            // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              _Item1,
              _Item2,
              _Item3,
              _Item4,
              model.isShowingAds ? _emptySpaceItem : null,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```